# Node.js Github API connect ECONNREFUSED error getting user repos

Tags: node.js, get, request, github-api, econnrefused

#### I'm locally attempting to get [user repos](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repositories-for-a-user) via [`https`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) get request with [`https.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback)

```js
const https = require("https")

https.get({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/ryanve/repos"
  }, response => {
    let data = ""
    response
      .on("data", chunk => data += chunk)
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log(data)
      })
  })
  .on("error", e => {
    console.error(e.message)
  })
```

#### I get an `ECONNREFUSED` error

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
```

What causes this error?

Authentication?

How do I fix?

`node --version` is `v12.16.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include `url` in an object that you pass to `get`. Since that's all you passed and it was ignored, it used a default URL of localhost. (IMO, having a default URL and not just throwing an error saying a URL is missing is a wart in NodeJS, but that's neither here nor there.) Replace this:

```
https.get({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/ryanve/repos"
  }
```

With this:

```
https.get("https://api.github.com/users/ryanve/repos"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps to get it working

1. [Corrected the `url` syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61357538/770127) Thanks!
2. Got [Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header](http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required) error
3. Tested that `curl` worked to same endpoint
4. Learned how to send `User-Agent` in `options.headers`

#### Working `curl`

```
curl -iH User-Agent:ryanve https://api.github.com/users/ryanve/repos
```

#### Working `https.get`

```
https.get("https://api.github.com/users/ryanve/repos", {
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "ryanve"
    }
  }, response => {
    let data = ""
    response
      .on("data", chunk => data += chunk)
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data, null, 2))
      })
  })
  .on("error", e => {
    console.error(e.message)
  })
```